# Does "-een" denote endearment?

Tags: meaning, expressions, literature, lolita

When reading Nabokov's *The Annotated Lolita* I came across these two terms on p. 104: **girleen**, **Laureen**.

> After all, Dante fell madly in love with his Beatrice when she was nine, a sparkling **girleen**, painted and lovely, and bejeweled, in a crimson frock, and this was in 1274, in Florence, at a private feast in the merry month of May.

And:

> And when Petrarch fell madly in love with his **Laureen**, she was a fair-haired nymphet of twelve running in the wind, in the pollen and dust, a flower in flight, in the beautiful plain as descried from the hills of Vaucluse.

My question is: does the desinence "-een" denote endearment? Could it be applied to other words and names?

Comment: In the US the suffix "-een" is occasionally used when referring to a "tween" -- a child in the age range of roughly 10-13.  It's not a well-established practice, though, and such use is somewhat jocular.  "Laureen", of course, is simply a name.

Comment: @HotLicks Laureen may well be a name, but of course Petrarch's attraction was to **Laura**, so it does rather appear as if an affix is being used.

Comment: @AakashM - In the US "Laureen" is simply a name.  Some thought may be given to the etymology when the parents choose the name (mainly to avoid bad associations), but few people would attach special meaning when being introduced to someone with that name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The suffix [***-een***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-een) does exist as a suffix in English, but it is not a very common one, and it is not really productive outside Ireland. Even in Ireland, it enjoys only limited productivity.

### In Irish

The suffix comes from the Irish Gaelic diminutive suffix *-ín*, which does indeed indicate that something is small and endearing. Like Romance languages, Irish has quite a few different diminutive suffixes that can be employed fairly freely. *-ín* is probably the most frequent one, but other very common ones are [*-án*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%C3%A1n) (which was originally only a diminutive, but is now more common in forming other types of words) and [*-óg*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%C3%B3g) (as in *seamróg*, which is Anglicised as ‘shamrock’—it’s nothing to with rocks, just a diminutive of [*seamair*](http://www.teanglann.ie/en/fgb/seamair) ‘clover’, with the Irish *-óg* replaced by the formerly common English diminutive [*-ock*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ock)).

In Irish, it can be added to both common nouns and proper names (both male and female, similar to *-y/-ie* in English), but since it is so productive and common nouns outnumber proper names by a factor of something very high, the number of common nouns in *-ín* is of course much higher than the number of proper names in *-ín*. Wiktionary has a whole [list of Irish words with this suffix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%C3%ADn#Irish), and many more can be made on the spot.

It is also frequently used to represent the very common English diminutive(-ish) suffix [*-ing*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#Etymology_3), such as in *góislín* ‘gosling’ or *féirín* ‘fairing [gift bought at a fair]’.

### In English

The diminutive *-een* suffix borrowed from Irish doesn’t appear in many common nouns in English, at least not words that are used much outside Ireland. Even in Ireland, the number of common nouns suffixed with *-een* is fairly small. [*Girleen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/girleen) is one of the ones you’ll occasionally hear in Ireland, but I’ve never heard it anywhere else. A more common one found both in and outside Ireland is *colleen*, which is a direct Anglicising of Irish *cailín* ‘girl’, a diminutive of [*caile*](http://www.teanglann.ie/en/fgb/caile) ‘girl, wench’. (Bizarrely, *colleen* is missing from the list of English words suffixed with *-een* on the Wiktionary page.)

Quite a lot of the proper names that are suffixed with *-ín* in Irish, however, have corresponding English forms in *-een* (and one or two common Irish nouns have been reinterpreted as proper names in English), but **they are all female names**. Male names are never diminutised with *-een* in English, unlike in Irish. The reason for this is probably that there is a French suffix [*-ine*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ine), which is exclusively feminine and frequently appears in personal names as well; it means something like ‘belonging to’ or ‘showing traits of’, which is a common way of forming personal names.<sup>1</sup>

In Irish, when they borrowed French names with this suffix, it just merged with their own diminutive suffix and it wasn’t so very strange that all the French ones happened to be feminine—the Irish one was still perfectly useful for both genders still. In English, however, there was no indigenous suffix for *-ine* to merge with, so it remained limited to its feminine usage in French. By the time the Irish names suffixed with *-ín* started being borrowed into English, the /iːn/ suffix was apparently already so fixed from French as a feminine suffix that the male names thus suffixed were just not borrowed.

So English has personal names that end in /iːn/ from (at least) two different sources, Irish and French, and many of them are tangled up enough that it’s hard to know which of the two is the more relevant origin of a name. Some examples:

- **Colleen**, from Irish *cailín* ‘girl’ (see above)
- **Maureen**, from Irish *Máirín* (diminutive of *Máire* ‘Mary’)
- **Eileen**, from Irish *Eibhlín* (from French *Aveline*)
- **Laureen**, from Irish *Láirín* (diminutive of *Lára* ‘Laura’) and/or French *Laurine*
- **Cathleen**, from Irish *Caitlín* (from French *Cateline*, a variant of *Catherine*) and/or French *Cateline*

As mentioned above, though, the suffix is not really productive in English. If you’re in Ireland, you may get away with forming such nonce uses as *lasseen* (‘wee lass’ = little girl) in conversation, but generally you’re limited to using the words that already exist, like *girleen* (little girl), *maneen* (little man), *poteen* (moonshine), *velveteen* (a type of fabric), *spalpeen* (rascal), etc. None of these are particularly common words, either.

If you used it productively and talked about your dear little *careen* (car), most people would probably be quite nonplussed and not know what you meant.

So yes, it is a diminutive suffix that signifies endearment and smallness—but it is not a productive one, and using it as such would not be natural and would most likely just confuse people.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The French *-ine* suffix also shows up in common nouns as well, and it is variously spelt *-ine* (as in *heroine*, *medicine*, etc.) and *-een* (as in *canteen* and *tureen*). The French suffix shows up, as you can see, in many words that are far more common than the ones containing the Irish *-ín* suffix.</sup>

<sup>The French suffix is inherited from the Latin suffix *-īnus* (> French *-in*), feminine *-īna* (> French *-ine*). This is ultimately cognate with the Irish *-ín* suffix (which is from Proto-Celtic **-īnos*), as well as with English [*-en*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-en#Etymology_4) (as in ‘wooden’),  Greek *-ῑνος*, and a host of other similar suffixes throughout the Indo-European languages. The ultimate origin of the suffix isn’t entirely clear: the commonly reconstructed Proto-Indo-European form is [**-iHnos*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-iHnos); it may or may not be somehow related to the so-called [Hoffmann suffix **-h₃onh₂-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-h%E2%82%83onh%E2%82%82-).</sup>

Comment: Great answer, just to add a little about its use: on a name -ín is normally only used in a cute/joking way for very small children or to distinguish a child from a parent of the same name (ie. It's the same as calling someone "David junior" etc). To use it to for an adult is typically an insult, joke, or something family members do out of habit (with the exception of a few names like Maureen, where the -een is standard and part of the given-name from birth).When used for other words, while speaking english, it's a joke/deliberate affection.

Comment: @Niall For male names where the suffix isn’t part of the actual name, that is generally true; _Tomáisín_ would either be a child or a cutesy way of calling a Thomas ‘Tommy’, for example, while someone called _Oisín_ would probably be both nonplussed and potentially offended at being de-diminutised to _Os_. For female names, it’s more fluid, I feel—probably because there are so many female names that have no corresponding non-diminutive female form (Bláithín, Seosaimhín, Pádraigín…). I’ve definitely heard guys call their girlfriends _Soirchín_ or _Áinín_, though.

Comment: I don't think we disagree about much here. As I said, exception is made for any name where the -een is part of the name as given. There's no diminutive being applied by others here, it's simply their name so there can be no joke or insult. Re: "Áinín"etc,  that's definitely a cutesy joke.

Comment: incidentally, "Bláthnaid".

Comment: Velveteen is a particularly common word. This answer was nice until the ill founded admonition of your last clause. And, Pauleen is worth a mention.

Comment: **Canteen** and **tureen** (both OED, from French -een)  are common enough common  nouns. And your answer would be more comprehensive had you mentioned that the French suffix derives  from a Latin one.

Comment: @Niall No, I meant that I've definitely heard _Áinín_ as a general hypocoristic: in a manner meant to be endearing, cutesy and probably a bit ingratiating, but not joking as such. I've absolutely also heard the joking, even mocking, use, but also the ‘regular’ diminutive use.

Comment: @Clare _Velveteen_ may be more common than the others, but it's still not particularly common unless you happen to work with fabrics. I stand by my admonition that _-een_ should not in general be used as a productive diminutive-forming suffix, any more than _-ock_ should. I did actually have the Latin (and indeed Indo-European origin of the French suffix, but removed it since it wasn't really relevant.

Comment: How many people who have heard of *The Velveteen Rabbit* happen to work with fabrics, I wonder. Also, if people listened to such ill founded admonitions, their creativity would be stifled.

Comment: @Clare The fact that a word appears in a commonly known work of fiction does not mean the word itself is common. Everyone knows _Through the Looking Glass_, but I don't recall the last time I heard anyone call their mirror a looking glass. Sure, if you know what you're doing, go ahead and be creative with your language—just be prepared that people will not understand you if you're creative with elements that aren't generally productive. If you want to use _beech_ as the plural of _book_ or _bookock_ as a diminutive of it, go ahead. But neither is a productive process.

Comment: Creativity is not the servant of either "productivity" or "clarity". Also, **canteen**.

Comment: @Clare Creativity is not the servant of **anything**, as the plurdled gabbleblotchits of any freddled gruntbuggly knows. It’s also not normal language usage, which is what we’re talking about here. _Canteen_ is, as you yourself said earlier, from French and has a different suffix (from the point of view of English, anyway). There are many common words with that suffix, but they’re not relevant to the Irish suffix. The French suffix is not generally a diminutive (a canteen is not a small cant, and medicine is not a small medic), unlike the Irish suffix. Added more info in a note.

Comment: 'Happy birthday, sweet sixteen' does not share this etymology.

Comment: Although no one is entirely positive about its precise origins, scholars think that **smithereens** likely developed from the Irish word smidiríní, which means "little bits." That Irish word is the diminutive of smiodar, meaning "fragment." (from Merriam-Webster)

Comment: @m69 Oh yes, forgot about that one—perhaps the commonest of all the Irish _-een_ words. There's a whole bunch more about _smidiríní_ and various other (probably) related, (probably) onomatopoeic words in [an old answer of mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133066/where-does-the-word-smidgen-come-from/133088#133088) as well.

Comment: [**Figurine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurine). An English word with French suffix. Not necessarily feminine but definitely small and endearing. Just a thought, I am Dutch and a layman in etymology.

Comment: @Draakhond See the footnote.

Comment: Janus B J, I have read the footnote with great interest. In [one of your comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405590/does-een-denote-endearment/405595?noredirect=1#comment965418_405595) you write "The French suffix is not generally a diminutive". Another good point. The only English word with French suffix that I could think of that ís a diminutive is "figurine". It is of course not a big thing (pun not intended) since the question is about "-een".

Comment: @Draakhond Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, that is actually a diminutive with the suffix. That word (and probably a few others) originated in Italian/Spanish/Portuguese, where the _-ino/-ina_ suffix functions as a diminutive more frequently than in French.

Comment: A minute ago I found these [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language) under "-ina/-ine/-ini/-ino" and I followed the links to the words: _linguine_ (Italian), _doctrine_ (from Latin) and _tambourine_ (French).